# python dictionary structure, speed concerns

Tags: python, data-structures

I am new to python. I need a data structure to store counts of some objects. For example, I want to store the most visited webpages. Lets say. I have 100 the most visited webpages. I keep the counts of visits to each webpage. I may need to update the list. I will definitely update the visit-counts. It does not have to be ordered. I will look at the associated visit-count given the webpage ID. I am planning to use a dictionary. Is there a faster way of doing this in python?

Comment: `how fast is the python dictionary structure?` Very fast.

Comment: The title may be somewhat wrong. But, I think my concern is understandable. I want to know whether it is the fastest or not for my purpose. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: You could also see if [`collections.counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) fits your needs.

Comment: @gokhan_ufl: sorry for the irony on your original question title, but this really sounds like premature optimization. One of the main data types in a popular programming languages is *bound* to be optimized by lots of clever folk to be as efficient as possible. Considering your question: if you're counting which pages get hit on your website -> are you reimplementing a server log?

Comment: @ChristopheD: I am not optimizing anything. Just trying to have an idea about it. Maybe, it is very fast for lookup but that fast for entry replacement. As I said, I am new to python. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary is an appropriate and fast data structure for this task (mapping webpage IDs to visit counts).

Python dictionaries are implemented using [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for fast O(1) access.  They are so fast that almost any attempt to avoid them will make code run slower and make the code unpleasant to look at.

P.S.  Also take a look at [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) which is specifically designed for this kind of work (counting hits).  It is implemented as a dictionary with initial default values set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionary object is one of the most optimized parts of the whole Python language and the reason is that dictionaries are used everywhere.

For example normally every object instance of every class uses a dictionary to keep instance data members content, the class is a dictionary containing the methods, the modules use a dictionary to keep the globals, the system uses a dictionary to keep and lookup the modules and so on.

For keeping a counter using a dictionary is a good approach in Python.